# xpath for parsing in Python

Tags: python, xpath

I've written a simple parser in Python for this [website](http://www.toponymic-dictionary.in.ua/index.php?option=com_content&view=section&layout=blog&id=1&Itemid=2). Below is part of my code.
My questions are:

1. How could I extract not only `p[1]` but also the rest `p[2]`,`p[3]`...
2. How Can I separate them from each other?

---

```
text1 = xmldata.xpath('//p[@class="MsoNormal"][1]//text()')  
a=''  
for i in text1:  
a=a+i.encode('cp1251')  
print a
```

Comment: can you share more of your code? what package are you using? `lxml`?

Comment: Here is the beginning of my code.                                                                                                                                                          import urllib
import lxml.html
page1 = urllib.urlopen('http://www.toponymic-dictionary.in.ua/index.php?option=com_content&view=section&layout=blog&id=1&Itemid=2')
pageWritten = page1.read()
pageReady = pageWritten.decode('utf-8')
xmldata = lxml.html.document_fromstring(pageReady)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lxml.html.parse()` function that accepts file-like objects, such as what `urllib.urlopen()` returns. See [lxml documentation on that](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#the-parse-function).

Then, as @CharlesDuffy suggests, you can use `u'\n'.join()` to concatenate all text elements within the `p` elements you select, with newlines `\n`

Also, I would suggest working with unicode strings all along, until you need to print or write to file.

```
import urllib
import lxml.html

page = urllib.urlopen('http://www.toponymic-dictionary.in.ua/index.php?option=com_content&view=section&layout=blog&id=1&Itemid=2')

# use "page" as a file-like object
xmldata = lxml.html.parse(page).getroot()

ptexts = xmldata.xpath('//p[@class="MsoNormal"]//text()')
joined_text = u'\n'.join(ptexts)

print joined_text.encode('cp1251')
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove the `[1]` to stop filtering, and your return value will be a list, which you can pass to `''.join()` to concatenate (or `'\n'.join()` if you want newlines between each string).

```
text_sections = xmldata.xpath('//p[@class="MsoNormal"]//text()')
print u'\n'.join(text_sections).encode('cp1251')
```

Comment: Actually I want newlines between each paragragh. In the result I want each p[1],p[2],... to be separated from each other.

Comment: @KhrystynaPyurkovska, that's what the code I provide above will do.

Answer (score 0):

without knowing of any background, I can suggest only such:

```
texts = list();
index = 0;
while(True):
    index += 1;
    try:
        temp = xmldata.xpath('//p[@class="MsoNormal"][%i]//text()' % index);
    except:
        break;
    else:
        texts.append();
```

after this block of code you will have a list of same elements as your `text1`